# How to restrict WPF programs with specific startup parameters to only one instance

Tags: wpf, parameters

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var args = e.Args;
        if(args.Length!=0)
        {
            if (args[0] == ("login"))
            {
                new LoginWindow().Show();//conduct the login procedure
            }
            if (args[0] == ("restart"))
            {
                new SmallPanelWindow(2).Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS", "--proxy-server=\"direct://\"");
            new MainWindow().Show();//show mainwindow which is commonly used
        }
    }
```

How can I ensure the LoginWindow exist only one at a time when the program is called with parameter "login" for multiple times?(eg. different triggers in windows TaskScheduler call the program with "login")Also, Starting Mainwindow can't be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Mutex` to ensure that only a single process at a time can open the `LoginWindow`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var args = e.Args;
    if (args.Length!=0)
    {
        if (args[0] == ("login"))
        {
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "8da112cb-a833-4c50-be53-79f31b2135ca"))
            {
                if (mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
                {
                    new LoginWindow().ShowDialog(); //conduct the login procedure
                }
                else
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        if (args[0] == ("restart"))
        {
            new SmallPanelWindow(2).Show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS", "--proxy-server=\"direct://\"");
        new MainWindow().Show();//show mainwindow which is commonly used
    }
}
```

You may want to to move the initialization of the `SmallPanelWindow` inside the `using` statement depending on your requirements but the above sample code should give you the idea.